# How is this C++ code running in GCC but not Visual C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
  int m;
  cin>>m;
  int re[m];
  cout<<sizeof(re);
}
```

This code is running perfectly in codeforces GNU C++ 4.7(But not in my Microsoft Visual C++). But why?
shouldn't the array size be a constant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned, C++ array sizes must be constant expressions.
- With VS, you will get:  `error C2057: expected constant expression`
- GCC has an extension to the standard, which allows your code to compile.

Answer (score 4):

Variable length arrays are introduced in C99. Standard C++ doesn't support it, but GCC supports it as an extension:

See [GCC extension: Arrays of Variable Length](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length) for detail.

Answer (score 3):

For stack allocation, array size needs to be determined at compile time. But the array size is determined at runtime, so it must go on the heap.

Use

```
int *re = new int[m];
cout << m << endl;
delete[] re;
```

Comment: True, but not answering the question. The OP is asking why it works in GCC.

Comment: Well, yes, but that question could be asked about any number of things. "Why does this non-standard thing work instead of crashing?"

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned, your code is non-standard C++ as you have a *variable length array*:

```
  int m;
  cin>>m;
  int re[m]; // m is not a compile time constant!
```

GCC allows this as *language extension*. You get a warning if you enable `-Wvla`. Afaik, this code gets rejected if you enfore gcc to use a specific c++ standard, such aus `-std=c++11`.

Now you _could do this instead (as Paul Draper already wrote)

```
int *re = new int[m]; // dynamic array allocation
delete[] re;          // giving the memory back to the operating system
```

However, C++ provides an easy to use wrapper for this:

```
std::vector<int> re(m);
```

For most things, vector behaves just like a dynamically allocated array, but prevents you from accidentally forgetting to `delete` or double `delete` and makes passing the data to functions a bit easier. Learn more about vector on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: i already know about vectors and dynamic allocation... i just wanted to know why this code works....

Comment: @TamojitChatterjee Well that's good, but others may not. Someone may find this question in the future. Then it's good if there is a reliable alternative mentioned in at least one answer.